# Firebird - Recuperar Banco de Dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebird

Estou tentando recuperar um banco de dados corrompido utilizando os utilitários do próprio Firebird.
Ao logar no banco acusa o seguinte erro:

> database file appears corrupt ()
>
> bad checksum
>
> checksum error on database page 21708

Tentei alguns procedimentos pelo gfix e pelo gbak :

```
gfix -v -f -i DADOS
gfix -m -i DADOS
gbak -g -b -z -l -v DADOS
```

Não obtive sucesso em nenum caso.

Somente tive este retorno de diferente :

> wrong page type
>
> page 21708 is of wrong type (expected 3, found 69)

Alguém já tentou recuperar bancos com este tipo de erro? 
Utilizo Firebird 2.5

Answer (score 1):

Então vamos lá, primeiro recomendo verificar novamente se retorna algum erro... utilize este comando para saber, estando dentro da pasta com o cmd aberto nela.

```
gfix -v -full caminho_da_base -user nome_usuario -pass senha_usuário
```

Exemplo

```
gfix -v -full C:\Sistema\banco.fdb -user SYSDBA -pass masterkey
```

Caso retorne erro, que é muito provavél, execute esse código para tentar reparar/ recuperar

```
gfix -m -i caminho_da_base -user nome_usuario -pass senha_usuário
```

Exemplo

```
gfix -mend -full -ignore C:\Sistema\banco.fdb -user SYSDBA -pass masterkey
```

Caso isso não funcione, entre neste [link](http://delphiparainiciantes.com.br/diagnosticando-e-recuperando-banco-de-dados-firebird-corrompido/) que tem algo mais completo

Comment: Amigo, este são os comandos que já tentei. Até mesmo por este link que você passou. Obrigado

Comment: https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/reparar-bd-firebird-corrompido/59054

Comment: Veja se este ajuda

Comment: Verifiquei um erro parecido, porém não ouve sucesso ao restaurar.

Comment: https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/25136

Comment: Fiz os procedimentos dos links porém sempre obtenho o mesmo resultado. Agradeço pelo empenho, mas acredito que não será possível recuperar este banco. Li algo sobre alterar o valor da página com erro por um editor hexadecimal, mas não consegui localizar o registro com erro.

Comment: Você não chegou a fazer um bakcup que possa recuperar? pois aparentemente esse erro/ corrompimento não tem volta :(

Comment: Tenho um backup porém um pouco antigo. Foi devido a falha no HD que sofreu uma queda.